# I want change dataLayer name but there is always a 'message'

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I want to send a datalayer with javascript on an e-commerce site that I am interested in. but dataLayer name always comes as a 'message'. Can I change that.

[datalayer screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiyKe.png)

```
    $(".dl-view-item").hover(function () {
        var a = $(this).data("dlname");
        window.dataLayer.push({ 'ecommerce': { 'currencyCode': 'TRY' }, 'impressionss': { 'name': a, } });

    });
```

Comment: Could you explain the question a bit more with an example of what do you have now and how do you want it to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how it is done.

```
window.dataLayer.push({
 'event':'Name', 
 'ecommerce': { 'currencyCode': 'TRY' }, 
 'impressionss': { 'name': a, } 
});
```

it works like this.

Answer (score 0):

The GTM preview pane displays a "message" when values are pushed to the datalayer without a corresponding event.

Without an event, no triggers will be called to fire a tag, and the internal state of GTM will not be updated with the newly added values.

So the message alerts you to the fact that for now you have added something to the window variable "dataLayer", but that you cannot yet use it within GTM (this why adding an event in the example in your self-answer fixes things).